# Can Oracle Virtualbox open vmdk virtual disk created by VMWare?

Tags: virtualbox, vmdk

I have a vmdk virtual disk that was created by VMWare. Can I option and load it from VirualBOX?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it can open them [directly](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch05.html#vdidetails) and use it for storage like its own formats.

Answer (score 4):

Open VirtualBox and create a new virtual machine, or open an existing one.
Click the "Settings" button
Click Storage
Click SATA Controller
Click Add Hard Disk
Navigate to and double-click on the VDMK file.
Click OK to save the setting.